# Example for converges series and non-converges series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We know that: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ absolutely convergent $\Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_n)^2$ convergent.

Now, I need to know if the opposite direction is true. If not I need to give a negative  example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Just change $n=0$ to $n=1$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is con.
But $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is not, I'm right?

Comment: you're totally right :D

Answer (score 0):

No. is not true and here is the example:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$  is con. but$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$ is not con. (it's div.) so of course it's not absolutely convergent.

$\blacksquare$